# How can I link a file download with a Progress View

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiprogressview

My button code below download a file from a URL, I need to link it with a Progress View to show the Downloading Progress.

```
@IBAction func btnStream(sender: UIButton) {

    //  First you need to create your audio url

    if let audioUrl = NSURL(string: "http://website.com/file.mp3") {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent!)
        println(destinationUrl)
        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(destinationUrl.path!) {
            println("The file already exists at path")

            // if the file doesn't exist
        } else {

            //  just download the data from your url
            if let myAudioDataFromUrl = NSData(contentsOfURL: audioUrl){
                // after downloading your data you need to save it to your destination url
                if myAudioDataFromUrl.writeToURL(destinationUrl, atomically: true) {
                    println("file saved")
                } else {
                    println("error saving file")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

How can i link my downloading progress with a Progress View in Swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is complete working example for you:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressCount: UILabel!

    var task : NSURLSessionTask!

    var percentageWritten:Float = 0.0
    var taskTotalBytesWritten = 0
    var taskTotalBytesExpectedToWrite = 0

    lazy var session : NSURLSession = {
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
        config.allowsCellularAccess = false
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        return session
        }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)  //set progressBar to 0 at start
    }

    @IBAction func doElaborateHTTP (sender:AnyObject!) {

        progressCount.text = "0%"
        if self.task != nil {
            return
        }

        let s = "http://www.qdtricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/hd-wallpapers-1080p-for-mobile.png"
        let url = NSURL(string:s)!
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        let task = self.session.downloadTaskWithRequest(req)
        self.task = task
        task.resume()

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten writ: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite exp: Int64) {
        println("downloaded \(100*writ/exp)")
        taskTotalBytesWritten = Int(writ)
        taskTotalBytesExpectedToWrite = Int(exp)
        percentageWritten = Float(taskTotalBytesWritten) / Float(taskTotalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        progressBar.progress = percentageWritten
        progressCount.text = String(format: "%.01f", percentageWritten*100) + "%"
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {
        // unused in this example
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        println("completed: error: \(error)")
    }

    // this is the only required NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate method

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {

        let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
        println("Finished downloading!")
        println(documentsDirectoryURL)
        var err:NSError?

        // Here you can move your downloaded file
        if NSFileManager().moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(downloadTask.response!.suggestedFilename!), error: &err) {
            println("File saved")
        } else {
            if let err = err {
                println("File not saved.\n\(err.description)")

            }
        }

    }

}
```

You can use `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` to achieve this whose method will be called when user downloading data.

This will show you the process into `progressCount` label and the `progressBar` will show process as count will increment. you can modify this as per your need.

You can download this example from [HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Show-download-with-progressBar).

Comment: Dharmesh Kheni, you example works fine but where do you save your file ?

Comment: Hi @DharmeshKheni . How to work for multiple URL. I am trying that only. I couldnt. If 2nd URL is progressing,, on that time if I start third URL means, 2nd is stopped. I dont know to run all url in concurrency. I am trying in swift. Pls guide me.

Comment: Feel free to open another question like how to work with multiple URL with this method..:)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023785/swift-how-can-i-download-datas-from-multiple-url-in-concurrency-mode

Comment: @DharmeshKheni If u know,, pls guide me.

Comment: Can you explain why the println in didFinishLoadingToURL doesn't get printed? Also, how can you access the destinationURL ? thanks

Comment: @DharmeshKheni your code work like charm. may you please tell me how to download multiple video and if downloading not completed then store in cache?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni there is no need to update the `UIProgressView` manually anymore iOS11+. `progressBar.observedProgress = task.progress` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/2908821-progress

Answer (score 2):

Check [this tutorial](http://www.devfright.com/ios-data-download-progress-bar-tutorial/). It's in Objective-C, but it will be easy to convert to Swift.

The principle is to implement some `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`functions on your VC :

- **connection:didReceiveResponse** -> You can retrieve the size of the file that will be downloaded and estimate the download percentage with it.
- **connection:didReceiveData** -> It's the refresh function, it will be called multiple times during the download. You can compare the size of your incomplete NSData object with the size of the file.
- **connectionDidFinishLoading** -> This method is called at the end of the download process.

Hope it helps, and don't hesitate to comment if you have some troubles converting Obj-C to Swift.