# Download multiple video and audio

Tags: ios, swift, download

I have made one demo in which i have to do download multiple video and audio so i found one library [from github](https://github.com/SagarSDagdu/SDDownloadManager). But i do not know how to save donwloading progress when i quite app(means when downloading done 50% and i want to save 50% video data in Document directory but when i open app downloading start from initial)

Code which i had used in my demo.

```
self.progressView.setProgress(0, animated: false)
    self.progressLabel.text = "0.0 %"
    self.finalUrlLabel.text = ""

    let request = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mp4")!)

    let downloadKey = SDDownloadManager.shared.dowloadFile(withRequest: request,
                                                           inDirectory: directoryName,
                                                           withName: nil,
                                                           onProgress:  { [weak self] (progress) in
                                                            let percentage = String(format: "%.1f %", (progress * 100))
                                                            self?.progressView.setProgress(Float(progress), animated: true)
                                                            self?.progressLabel.text = "\(percentage) %"
                                                            print("percentage",percentage)
    }) { [weak self] (error, url) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error is \(error as NSError)")
        } else {
            if let url = url {
                print("Downloaded file's url is \(url.path)")
                self?.finalUrlLabel.text = url.path
            }
        }
    }

    print("The key is \(downloadKey!)")

    let dasd = SDDownloadManager.shared.ongoingDownloads
    print("dasd",dasd.count)
```

If you know any other solution please help me via your best experience in downloading progress.
TIA

**Edit**:

I have used this [Link for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295805/how-can-i-link-a-file-download-with-a-progress-view) For downloading video using url session. But don't know how to resume download when application terminated and open again.

Comment: Had similar problem i have been using if any one know please answer it

Answer (score 1):

first thing SDDownloadManager says Resumable Downloads not implemented yet in the framework. Its mentioned there as below

Future Enhancements
I'm planning to integrate the following features in upcoming releases :

```
Background Downloads.
Resumable Downloads.
```

so you cant achieve this using this. Instead you can use NSUrlSession to
achieve this.

Comment: how can i do that with NSUrlSession ? @ vivekDas

Comment: I would suggest you to go through the below tutorial, its really good and u will definitely get your ans https://www.raywenderlich.com/158106/urlsession-tutorial-getting-started if you dont get anything in this tutorial you can ask me I can help you on that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have follow `URLSession` as per your suggestion.may you please tell me how to resume download video if user quite the app and open again. I have updated question. please check @ vivekDas

Comment: See if user forcefully quit the app using app switcher then your app will not get any callback so you cant do anything. If user press the home button then your app will get delegate callback [applicationDidEnterBackground] there you have a chance to save the resumed data and restart download on relaunching the app again. But you can enable background download and continue downloading in the background check the "Enabling Background Transfers" section in the same tutorial I mentioned.